# My Nested For loops Run "faster" than inline For loop

Tags: python, loops, time

For a class I'm in we are asked to write out a brute force method for finding 2 elements in lists *S1*, *S2*, that add to a specified value **x**. So far I have it written out as such:

```
@timing
def brute_force_nested(x, s1 : list, s2 : list) -> bool:
    for a in s2:
        for b in s1:
            if a + b == x:
                return True
    return False

@timing
def brute_force_inline(x, s1 : list, s2 : list) -> bool:
    return bool([ (a,b) for a in s2 for b in s1 if a + b == x ])
```

But when I run them in the terminal, I get a very large difference in times:

```
>>> brute_force_nested(5123, S1, S2):

func:brute_force_nested took: 0.007085800170898438 sec and gave: True

>>>func:brute_force_inline(5123, S1, S2)

func:brute_force took: 3.0208868980407715 sec and gave: True
```

Why is this happening? I was under the impression that the inline syntax was essentialy just syntactical sugar for written out nested loops, but something is obviously different, and I don't know what.

Comment: your nested for loop stop as soon as it find the the first match thank to the return; the list comprehension make a list with ALL the match fist and then give it the bool function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are only iterating over the lists in the first fuinction and returning on the first value. The second you are creating a list then evaluating the Truthy value of that list. For them to be comparable you need to use `any` and a generator comprehension.

```
def brute_force_inline(x, s1 : list, s2 : list) -> bool:
    return any(a + b == x for a in s2 for b in s1)
```

**P.S** Technically both of your approaches are nested loops one is just done using a comprehension.

This can also be done more efficiently using `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

def brute_force_inline(x, s1 : list, s2 : list) -> bool:
    return any(sum(ab) == x for ab in product(s2, s1))
```

Comment: How do you imagine the `product` one to be faster?

Comment: Because the nested for loop is ran in C vs native python. In this case the difference in efficiency is negligible.

Comment: `for a, b in` runs in Python just as much. But always has to assign *two* values instead of just one, making it *less* efficient. Can you show an input where it's more efficient?

Comment: Consider my edit.

Comment: [161 ms is more efficient than 67 ms](https://tio.run/##pVLdasMgFL73Kb6bUt2ykTS9GIXsRcYQbcwmRA3GQPr0mcYUdtHCyrw6Hs/3h2e4hG9n67fBL0vnnUHQRukAbQbnw3YjpFUdpJ@C4p3zZ8W17bVVFZ0LjBVO6PUYYnnYSoaXd0jn@hNBPF6FyVsIe6ECz5BoGsyITBDQNsFSLde6YoSsRnRQPkSK8epl8K6dznfNHP5vpsgeNiE6HhIhY/cU68cU58RtxEDHyRR/Fjk@HivyUyHZr2B3Ys1oUJJI3iTaBh/VJ55QlWVJEownlBf2S9GaZZXU7iZ7Ti839qG49S@3msdMl06IwnnNaC@MbMVpVcixU15WwE5GKt/E3biiBq9toPtd3cKM2GMHGpJ3VcfxhH/l3AqjOM@YPM@W5Qc)?

Comment: Weird... Always thought that would be quicker in most every situation. Do you know why that is? is it because it consumes the iterable before computing?

Comment: I guess having to iterate is one issue, yes. Another is loading and calling the `sum` function. At least the loading can be avoided, along with almost all Python work, as I did in my `brute_force_inline3` function there, which is a lot faster, but still slower than the first two. Yet another issue might be that `sum` computes `(0+a)+b`, although it's optimized so that might barely hurt at all. Overall I can't point to one thing and say "that's why", they're just so different.

Answer (score 2):

The loops are indeed equal, but not the condition to break it. In the first nested loop, the code stops when the first equality is reached. In the second one, all tests are computed until all combinations are exhausted.

The equivalent of the first loop with the comprehension syntax would be to use a generator and `any`, that will stop when the first truthy value is reached

```
return any((a+b==x for a in s2 for b in s1))
```

Comment: @Jab thanks! Typing on my phone, not easy to have a good overview;)